# PayPal two transactions per mass payout, get ID of second transaction

Tags: paypal, payout

I create a payout with PayPal mass payouts api. The api than creates two transactions. I am able to get the payout id of the first transaction accessing payout_batch_id. I can’t get the id of the second. I’ll post a picture below.

[image: heres a image of the two payout transactions.]

The picture above shows two transactions for the same payout. I’m able to retrieve the id of the one labeled “mass payment sent” but not “money sent”.

Comment: possible there is no id until it has been accepted

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by accessing the items[0].transaction_id. The payout_batch_id accesses the mass payout. While items[0].transaction_id accessing the individual payout itself. The whole tag response.result.batch_header.payout_batch_id & response.result.items[0].transaction_id